# Angular dropdown select - how to set default value from typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to set default value in Select?

I am trying to create time- dropdown select with multiple options.
At present. the selectedTimeOption correctly identifies if we choose an option from dropdown, but can't detect a value that I am trying to display initially from the Typescript.

I want to first display a predefined value in select box even before selection (it basically  comes from another page)

How do I implement it?

Is there a problem with TS component or the html? If someone can explain with small working example on stackblitz.com , that would be helpful.

```
HTML:
        <select 
        
            [value]="selectedTimeOption"       
            (valueChange)="setTime($event)"
        >

        <option 
              "let option of timeOfOptions"
              [value]="option"
           >
                    {{ option.label }}
                
        </option>
        </select>
   
TS:
          timeOptions:TimeItems[] =[ 
          { label: '0:00', value: '0' }, 
          { label: '1:00', value: '1' }, 
          { label: '2:00', value: '2' }, 
          ];
```

Comment: your values should be inside to select tag

Comment: which values? would be nice to understand

Comment: you have to modify your question. you should n't be using option as variable name inside option  tag and you should use *ngFor to iterate over array

Comment: Im aware of that. Those are taken care. I've just left it like that is it throws some error while posting queston.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63192748/13596406

Answer (score 0):

Your <option tag should be like this:

```
<option [value]="option.value">
```

And your **selectedTimeOption** can be set to:

```
selectedTimeOption = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question, I am trying to display a value in the select and not the dropdown options. Hope I have conveyed it correctly now!

Comment: To display a value in the <select> tag, it must match one of the values in <option> tag

Comment: yes im checking the matching with one of the values in the <option> tag. Though selectedTimeOption is empty. Though it correctly identifies if we choose one among the option values in dropdown. What could be the reason?  Supposedly in TS file?

Comment: Can you add some sample <options> tag and its values in your question?

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: tried it. still the same. i dont have a problem with the options. Its just that the select recognizing the first value Im trying to display. 

ive currently initialized selectedTimeOption:

selectedTimeOption = this.timeOptions[0];

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at he [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-values-from-select) example here,

Where, you can initialize the value to be displayed first(as you said from another component) in the example it is shown  as,

```
firstSelectValue = 'one';
```

and then in your template, in your  element, you can have a 'getter', in the given example, it is,

```
*ngFor="let opt of firstSelectOptions"
```

Comment: Appreciate providing the example. Thats great. I have edited the question with more details. 

I have the firstSelectValue initial value to be displayed coming from another component. Would be great if you could explain how that can be implemented in the example component?

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax issue and coding conventions you need to follow. please rename those option variable while iterating over array, something like below.

ex: *ngFor = "let time of timeSource"

Here is the stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8rtcyw)

Comment: Thanks for the example. 
selectedTimeOption automatically displays the first array element in select? 

is it because of angular 10?

Comment: Not because of Angular10, dropdown takes the first value as the default value