# Angular: ngmodel creates blank select option in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Why `ngModel` is creating blank element in **HTML** - **select** - **option**? How can I get rid of this?

First code.

```
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="height: 3rem; width: max-content; margin-left: 33.5rem;" (change)="getSelectedUserAccess()">
      <option>suman</option>
      <option selected>rony</option>
      <option>alex</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Second code [wrong]

```
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p>Select User : </p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="currentSelectedUser" class="form-control" id="userSelect1"
      style="height: 3rem; width: max-content; margin-left: 33.5rem;" (change)="getSelectedUserAccess()">
      <option>suman</option>
      <option selected>rony</option>
      <option>alex</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

screnshot :

[image]

Comment: What is the value of currentSelectedUser variable in .ts file ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi blank, no value . It will get value when I call (change)="getSelectedUserAccess()"

Comment: initialize the ngModel in the component like this: export class Component implements OnInit {
  currentSelectedUser = 'rony';

or better use an array of name and initialize the ngModle with the first value of the array

Comment: @Christoph Right now, I am manually giving select option . But it will come from db, so i dont know what it will be then

Comment: @Frost and the first result from the database should be selected? Then I still would initialize it with an empty value(like you do) and set it after you get the result from the database

Comment: @Christoph Hmm, that's a possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize ngModel value with the value from database or 'rony'. Also maintain an array for list of users so that you can show the selectedCurrentUser as the selected user by default using `[selected]="currentSelectedUser===user"`.

html:

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p>Select User : </p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="currentSelectedUser" class="form-control" id="userSelect1"
      style="height: 3rem; width: max-content; margin-left: 33.5rem;" 
      (change)="getSelectedUserAccess()">
      <option *ngFor="let user of users" [selected]="currentSelectedUser === user"> 
      {{user}}
     </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

ts:

```
  users:Array<string>=['suman', 'alex', 'rony'];
  currentSelectedUser:string;

  constructor(private usrService:UserService){  }

  ngOnInit(){
   this.currentSelectedUser = this.usrService.getCurrentUser(); //rony
  }

  getSelectedUserAccess(){
    console.log("Current Selected User", this.currentSelectedUser)
  }
```