# Why does ngmodelChange event not fire when component loads on a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 8 component, I have added bi-directional binding to a dropdown control.

**The view**

```
<select  (ngModelChange)='termSelectChanged($event)' [ngModel]="selected">
  <option [ngValue]="t" *ngFor='let t of termsColl'>{{t?.code}}</option>
</select>
```

**The component code**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{


     public termsColl : Array<DDModel>;
     public selected : DDModel;
     
      constructor( private s : DDService ){}
      
    termSelectChanged( event  ){    
            alert('HIT');
    }
    
    
      ngOnInit(){
        
        //service call #1
        this.s.getDataForComplexBind().subscribe(  data => {
          this.termsColl = data;
         
        }, error => error );    


        //service call #2
        this.s.getOtherData(  ).subscribe( data => {
          
          //model changes here
          this.selected = this.termsColl[1];
          
        }, error => {  console.error(error);  });

                    
    }

}
```

When the component loads, it executes ngOnInit() and sets the model-bound property `Selected` with the first element of the array `termsColl`. `termsColl` has data but the line `this.selected = this.termsColl[1];` does not change the selected option to the first element in the dropdown. In fact, when the component loads, I was expecting it to fire the event `ngModelChange` but it did NOT fire the event either. I have added an `alert()` in the code but it did not show when the component loads. It shows only if I select an option from the dropdown. How do I change the code so it will execute the `ngModelChange` event when the component loads?

Here is my stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-version-yeg27j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It may help you Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy       i have updated my post with stakcblitz

Comment: I don't understand why do you need `(ngModelChange)` to fire when setting the value initially. Can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the `ngModeChange` input to `DDModel` and called your `termSelectChanged()` from inside the subscribe. I also changed `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]`

```html
<select  (ngModelChange)='termSelectChanged($event)' [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option [ngValue]="t" *ngFor='let t of termsColl'>{{t?.code}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
  termSelectChanged(selection: DDModel) {
    console.log("HIT", selection);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.s.getOtherData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.termsColl = data;
        this.selected = this.termsColl[0];
        this.termSelectChanged(this.selected);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I can't tell you why changing `this.selected` from code does not trigger the `ngModelChange`. Maybe it's because `ngModelChange` is called in the template.

Comment: your code works but there an issue, when i select an option from the drop down the "selection" object  in the termSelectChanged() will show the previously selected value?

Comment: I think that because of this statement `(ngModelChange)='termSelectChanged(selected)' ` just change the `selected` to `$event` or something. It should work in my guess

Answer (score 3):

You can use `viewToModelUpdate()` of `ngModel` to update the value and if you want to trigger the `ngModelChange`. You can find more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#viewtomodelupdate).

But you need to do the following changes.

In html template:

```html
<select  (ngModelChange)='termSelectChanged($event)' [ngModel]="selected" #ngModel="ngModel">
  <option [value]="t" *ngFor='let t of termsColl'>{{t?.code}}</option>
</select>
```

You can see I am adding a reference to the ngModel in template, which I will use it in the component class.

In the component class:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular 6";
  version = VERSION.full;

  public termsColl: Array<DDModel>;
  public selected: string;

  @ViewChild("ngModel") ngModel: NgModel;

  constructor(private s: DDService) {}

  termSelectChanged(event) {
    this.selected = event;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.s.getOtherData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.termsColl = data;
        this.ngModel.viewToModelUpdate(this.termsColl[1]);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

You can see I am using the `ngModel` reference to call the `viewToModelUpdate` with the value, which in return triggers the `ngModelChange`.

Since you are not using two way binding directly, you have to set the value to the `selected` variable inside the trigger function `termSelectChanged`.

Hope this would help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to call internal NgModel methods directly.

Comment: @Rishanthakumar  In your post that you have mentioned i'm not using "Direct model Binding". I was curious, if i would want to use "Direct Model binding", then how would i make the (ngModelChange) event fire when the component loads? Could you please post direct model binding along with the existing property binding as well?

Comment: @eutychostfar what I mentioned was about the "Two Way Binding", where we can put `[(ngModel)]="selected"`. So that you don't need to update the `this.selected` variable when the `ngModelChange` fired since it is bound both way. Any reason for you to trigger the `ngModelChange` initially, because in a simple way you can trigger that method from the same place you are updating the variable.

Comment: @Rishanthakumar The reason i want to execute the event on component load is, i want to get the object that i'm storing in the "value" property of the selected "option" of the drop down and this value will go through some processes later on. I have tried the method that was give by the stack overflow user "unassignedmind"( see below ) his technique works but when i select an option from the drop down "termSelectChanged()" will receive the previously selected object. So i was thinking that, there should be a proper way to do this?

Comment: @eutychostfar I think that because of this statement in his solution `(ngModelChange)='termSelectChanged(selected)'` just change the `selected` to `$event` or something. It should work in my guess.

Comment: @Rishanthakumar after making the changes that you have suggested, the answer given by stack user "unassignedmind" worked. So i have given him an upvote. But i could mark your(Rishanthakumar ) answer as a complete answer, if you could give the alternative solution using direct two-way binding as well?

Comment: @eutychostfar I think you should mark "unassignedmind" answer as correct since it is simple. May be my answer can stay here just for the knowledge. Again to make it direct two-way binding, you need to put this `[(ngModel)]="selected"` and also apart from that to make your solution work in addition to this `this.ngModel.viewToModelUpdate(this.termsColl[1]);` you need to assign the value for the variable in the subscription as well. And then you can remove the variable assignment in `ngModelChange` trigger.

Comment: @Rishanthakumar no issues, I will mark it as you have suggested and thank you for the tip on how to extend the code to support direct two way binding   : )

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value` instead of `ngValue` in you option elements. And assign `t.code` instead of `t` to the `value` attribute.

```
<select  (ngModelChange)='termSelectChanged($event)' [ngModel]="selected">
  <option [value]="t.code" *ngFor='let t of termsColl'>{{t?.code}}</option>
</select>
```

Reference: https://angular-version-xkjuff.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2):

**termsColl has data but the code line this.selected = this.termsColl[1]; does not change the selected option to the first element in the drop down.**

Because you are using propery binding [ngModel]="selected", not two-way data binding.

[(ngModel)]="selected" is for two-way binding, and the syntax is compound from:

[ngModel]="selected" and (ngModelChange)="selected = $event"

Also, the value of selected should be the value which is available in dropdown, i.e

```
ngOnInit(){
 
 this.selected = this.termsColl[1].code

}
```

Below code would work for you:

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onSelection()">
  <option  *ngFor='let t of termsColl' [value]="t.code" [selected]="selected === t.code">{{t?.code}}</option>
</select>
```

You might also want to refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63192748/13596406